# JS: two click events, how does JS decide which gets triggered first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand how JavaScript decides which event will be run first if the same event is bound to two separate elements. For example, in my JS I have:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
  //some code
})

$('#someButton').click(function(e){
  //some code
})
```

When I test this, no matter how I arrange the code (#someButton code before document or after) the #someButton click event always gets triggered first. How does JS decide what gets executed first?

Comment: Event bubbling. By default event listeners are triggered from deepest to outermost elements.

Comment: Aha. Event bubbling is what I was trying to figure out and what I need to read up on. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508225/how-is-the-order-of-event-listeners-in-javascript-determined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specification.

The id is more specific than the document.

Here is an example with a class button that is also more specific than the document.

```js
$(document).click(function(e){
    alert("Document");
})

$('#someButtonId').click(function(e){
    alert("Id");
})

$('#someButtonClass').click(function(e){
    alert("Class");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Demo.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

<button id="someButtonId">Button Id</button>
<button id="someButtonClass">Button Class</button>


<script  type="text/javascript" src="Demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```